# Bootstrap navbar items alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to build a very simple navbar with bootstap according to some online tutorials.

I am trying to align the navbar items horizontally but I keep getting the following formation:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
    <body>
      <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
          <div class='navbar-header'>
            <a href='#' class='navbar-brand'> $Whoami </a>
          </div>
          <ul class='nav navbar-inverse navbar-custom'>
            <li ><a href='#'>Skills</a></li>
            <li ><a href='#'>Interests</a></li>
            <li ><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <h1> Hello World! </h1>
    </body>
```

Comment: use the "float:left." style.  e.g. <li style="float:left;"><a href='#'>Skills</a></li>

Comment: This is plain css right? Will it affect the responsiveness of the page?

Comment: add *`navbar-nav`* to your *`<ul class="nav...`* like *`<ul class='nav nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse navbar-custom'>`* for maintain it responsive too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to just add **`navbar-nav`** to your **`ul`**

```
<nav class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <div class='navbar-header'>
        <a href='#' class='navbar-brand'> $Whoami </a>
      </div>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-inverse navbar-custom'>
        <li ><a href='#'>Skills</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Interests</a></li>
        <li ><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1> Hello World! </h1>
```

[image: Output image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h1> Hello World! </h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```